# Angular and Mustache

Tags: angular, mustache

For a while, I have been using Mustache for templating needs. I am about to learn Angular at my work, some time next week. What, if anything, should I expect? (For example, will Angular replace Mustache, or can I use them together in an application for good results?)

Comment: Will probably get closed, no technical answer possible => primarily opinion based.

Comment: Angular has its own templating system, so no, it wouldn't be a good idea to try to use Mustache within your Angular app.